# How do you increase the limit of an SQL query on click of a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server

This is my first year of programming and I'm trying to increase the *limit* of an SQL Query on click of a button.

Let's say I have:

```
<?php
    $number = 5;
    $db->query("SELECT * FROM results LIMIT $number"); 
?>

<div id='test'> Load content into me </div>
<button id='happy' value='Click Me'>
```

**How can I increase the value of `$number` on click of `#happy`**

This is what I thought of:

```
$("#happy").click(function() {
 $("#test").load("content.php"); 
});
```

**content.php**

```
<?php

$number+=20;

?>
```

If you load content into a page, don't both pages now share the same variables? Are there any security vulnerable with loading pages for data?

**What is the most efficient way to increase the limit of this SQL Query on click of a button?**

### @Louys Patrice Bessette

When I load the content from the other page, the *entire* page is added to that one review section. In case it wasn't clear, this review wiget isn't the only feature of this page...

Comment: I still consider my answer as acurate for the initial question. Now, you ADD related questions to it. 1st about security vulnerability --> Answer is NO. Because the GET used only change the result amount. 2nd is wider. It depends on the data you're extracting. And it isn't a problem for the DB, but maybe for the user... If you "flood" him with too much info (ex: a table 2000 table rows by 28 columns). Its is your developper's judgement here. 3rd : Sorry, I don't get it. Join me in chat for more talk! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/112984/for-question-37449907?tab=general

Comment: For the record. I ended the chat room 24hrs later. Could be nice to remove my name call in big fat bold withing the question.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the number you want in a GET.

```
$("#happy").click(function() {
 $("#test").load("content.php?limit=20"); // Or any number.
});
```

In your PHP:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['limit'])){
        $number=$_GET['limit'];
    }else{
        $number = 5;
    }
    $db->query("SELECT * FROM results LIMIT $number"); 
?>

<div id='test'> Load content into me </div>
<button id='happy' value='Click Me'>
```

Comment: Ho! I just saw this notification. Plz follow this link to continue in chat. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/112984/for-question-37449907?tab=general